# Code to open default email app on iOS & Android (TO CHECK FOR NEW MAIL, NOT TO SEND EMAIL )

Tags: android, ios, email, default

I am sending a confirmation link by email and would like to have a link to open their default email app on the phone on both iOS and Android so they can look for their most recent emails. I have seen others do this so I already know its possible. Does anyone know the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use this code

```
try {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
    this.startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    Log.d("No Email Client Installed")
}
```